# Read input to a file

Tags: mac-osx, unix

I'm looking for a unix command that is the opposite of `cat` (but not `tac`).

I want to do

```
$ SOMECOMMAND /tmp/file
I type some content
for the file here
^D
$ cat /tmp/file
I type some content
for the file here
$
```

So, I actually type in 'I type some content...' after running the command, and it is written to the file.  And before you suggest it, yes, I am very aware of editors -- just looking for something shorthand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The opposite of `cat` is `cat`.

```
$ cat > /tmp/file
I type some content
for the file here
^D
$ cat /tmp/file
I type some content
for the file here
$
```

Comment: HA!  I Love it.  Will accept as soon as the 15 min are up.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer is also an extremely useful method that I use frequently for adding multiple host file entries in one fail swoop: `# cat >> /etc/hosts` and then enter numerous IP/hosts on separate lines, and finally Ctrl-C when finished.